# In Excel, input values of one column based on value of another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have ten sheets representing ten years of data. In the sheets I have rows representing objects in images, with an attribute corresponding to the image the object is located in. The image number (Frame) is directly associated with date, and I would like to update the date column with the date based on the frame value. eg 1 -> 01/01/2014.

However there are thousands of records and doing this thousands of times over ten files isn't exactly feasible, as there are multiple objects on each day, so the sheet looks something like this.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I am not sure how to go about doing this in Excel.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain sufficient information to describe what you want to do (see my comment on teylyn's answer).  People are already spending time attempting to answer based on a guess as to what you mean, which really isn't fair to them.  I'm voting to close the question as unclear and will retract the vote once you clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming with "Frame" you are referring to the column with the title `TIME IN FRAMES` it looks like you want to use the value in that column as the day in a date value. So, if 1 should return Jan-01-2014, I assume that 23 should return Jan-23-2014.

Your data set does not show any values above 23 in that column, so it is hard to tell what you want to achieve for values like 32. Assuming that this should point to the 32nd day in the year 2014, and assuming that the first column in your screenshot is column A and the Date column is column L, then you can use the following formula in row 2 of the date column and copy down:

=date(2014,1,K2)

There are a lot of assumptions leading to this formula. The assumptions may be wrong. If so, update your question with the missing information and post a comment to notify people who are watching this question.

Comment: If I'm interpretting the screenshot correctly, it looks like the first field is the frame ID, which is translated to a date in the last field.  The Time in Frames column doesn't seem to relate to the date.  However, there isn't a clue to where the month comes from.